# Android ListView all views shows last item data

Tags: java, android, listview

I really need some good hint.... i have been hours debugging this (((...

```
public class Travel {
    public static String from, to;

    Travel(String f, String t) {
        this.from = f;
        this.to = t;
    }
}

final class NotesAdapter extendes ArrayAdapter<Travel>{
private final List<Travel> myC;

public NotesAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Travel> myCt) {
    super(context, resource, myCt);
    this.myC = myCt;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myC.size();
}

@Override
public Travel getItem(int position) {
    return myC.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup adapterView) {

    Travel trv = myC.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_lists, adapterView, false);
    }

    TextView from = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
    TextView to = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_to);

    from.setText(trv.from);//.getMFrom()
    to.setText(trv.to);//.getMTo()

    return convertView;
    }
```

In NotesAdapter i have implemented only the method you see here.
Then in the main activity i launch startactivityforresult and in the onactivityresults i add elements to the List object.

```
List<Travel> myCities = new ArrayList<Travel>();
```

the List object is initialized as an ArrayList (...new ArrayList<>()...). 
I also have:

```
mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.for_lists);
na = new NotesAdapter(this,R.layout.my_lists,myCities);
```

So:

```
nCity = data.getStringExtra("content");
```

to collect the new string

```
myCities.add(new Travel("Home Town",nCity));
```

to add a new travel.... and:

```
na.notifyDataSetChanged();
mList.setAdapter(na);
```

this is the all code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            nCity = data.getStringExtra("content");

                if (!myCities.contains(nCity)) {
                    myCities.add(new Travel("Home Town",nCity));
                    na.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"This City has already been added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
        else {
            //do something when user refused to complete action
        }

        hT.setText("Home Town");
        iB.setText(infoBar);

        na.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mList.setAdapter(na);
        mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            }
        });
    }
    else {
            // not my business another request
    }
 }
```

When i use just a List of String all works perfectly.
The result with a List of Travel is that all views in the listview show the last added travel.

For layout files i use basic implementations.

Please help... ^_^

Comment: If you'd like to get good answers then you need to know how to ask a good question :) Help page about [MCVE] would be a great start for you!

Answer (score 0):

`na` is never set to List until you call `mList.setAdapter(na);`. You don't need to call `na.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Please add one new method in `NotesAdapter` adapter. This method will update data:

```
public void updateData(List<Travel> myCt){
    this.myC = myCt;
}
```

then update your code

```
na.notifyDataSetChanged();
mList.setAdapter(na);
```

with

```
na.updateData(myCities);
mList.setAdapter(na);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506/why-does-my-arraylist-contain-n-copies-of-the-last-item-added-to-the-list)

```
public static String from, to
```