# repeated values are coming in listView in android

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm working on a `ListView` with a `BaseAdapter`. I am showing values from a `JSON` file to a `ListView`. My problem is that I am only getting the last value in every list Items,

**Activity**:

```
public class CustomerList extends Activity {
    ImageView ic_back;
    ListView lv_cust;
    LoadJson loadcustomers;
    String customers;
    ArrayList<Customer> customerList;
    CustomerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_list);
        lv_cust = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_customers);
        ic_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_back);
        loadcustomers = new LoadJson(CustomerList.this, "customers");
        customers = loadcustomers.loadJSONFromAsset();

        ic_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        //setting static data to list..
        fetchCustomers();
        adapter = new CustomerAdapter(CustomerList.this, customerList);
        lv_cust.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //end


    }

    //void fill row data..
    void fetchCustomers() {
        customerList = new ArrayList<>();
        customerList.clear();
        try {
            JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(customers);
            JSONObject dataObj = mainObj.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray customerArray = dataObj.getJSONArray("result");

            for (int i = 0; i < customerArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = customerArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                customer.setAccountNumber(c.getString("accountNumber"));
                customer.setAccountStatus(c.getString("accountStatus"));
                customer.setAccountType(c.getString("accountType"));
                customer.setCustomerCategory(c.getString("customerCategory"));
                customerList.add(customer);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
        }
```

**Adapter class**

```
public class CustomerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private final ArrayList<Customer> customer;
    Integer selected_position = -1;


    public CustomerAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Customer> customer) {
        mContext = c;
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return customer.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_customer, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv_account_no = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_act_no);
            holder.tv_act_sts = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_act_sts);
            holder.tv_act_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_act_name);
            holder.tv_cust_cat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cust_cat);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv_account_no.setText(customer.get(position).getAccountNumber());
        holder.tv_act_sts.setText(customer.get(position).getAccountStatus());
        holder.tv_act_name.setText(customer.get(position).getAccountType());
        holder.tv_cust_cat.setText(customer.get(position).getCustomerCategory());


        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_account_no;
        TextView tv_act_sts;
        TextView tv_act_name;
        TextView tv_cust_cat;
    }
}
```

**josn file**

```
{
  "code": 600,
  "status": "success",
  "message": null,
  "data": {
    "result": [
      {
        "accountNumber": "0000160057",
        "accountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "accountType": "ACT09",
        "address": "10jan2017wom1fttx5",
        "mobilePhone": "1235123412",
        "phone": null,
        "customerCategory": "VIP"
      },
      {
        "accountNumber": "0000160058",
        "accountStatus": "DEACTIVE",
        "accountType": "ACT11",
        "address": "10jan2017wom1fttx5",
        "mobilePhone": "33408805",
        "phone": null,
        "customerCategory": "VIP"
      },
      {
        "accountNumber": "0000160059",
        "accountStatus": "REGISTERED",
        "accountType": "ACT19",
        "address": "10jan2017wom1fttx5",
        "mobilePhone": "9976878756",
        "phone": null,
        "customerCategory": "Default"
      },
      {
        "accountNumber": "0000160064",
        "accountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "accountType": "ACT23",
        "address": "10jan2017wom1fttx5",
        "mobilePhone": "3556456745",
        "phone": null,
        "customerCategory": "VIP"
      },
      {
        "accountNumber": "0000160044",
        "accountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "accountType": "ACT67",
        "address": "10jan2017wom1fttx5",
        "mobilePhone": "3556456745",
        "phone": null,
        "customerCategory": "Default"
      },
      {
        "accountNumber": "0003460097",
        "accountStatus": "REGISTERED",
        "accountType": "ACT56",
        "address": "10jan2017wom1fttx5",
        "mobilePhone": "3556456745",
        "phone": null,
        "customerCategory": "Default"
      },
      {
        "accountNumber": "0000160099",
        "accountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "accountType": "ACT46",
        "address": "10jan2017wom1fttx5",
        "mobilePhone": "3556456745",
        "phone": null,
        "customerCategory": "Default"
      },
      {
        "accountNumber": "0000160090",
        "accountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "accountType": "ACT29",
        "address": "10jan2017wom1fttx5",
        "mobilePhone": "3556456745",
        "phone": null,
        "customerCategory": "VIP"
      },
      {
        "accountNumber": "0000160044",
        "accountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "accountType": "ACT55",
        "address": "10jan2017wom1fttx5",
        "mobilePhone": "3556456745",
        "phone": null,
        "customerCategory": "VIP"
      },
      {
        "accountNumber": "0000160045",
        "accountStatus": "REGISTERED",
        "accountType": "ACT23",
        "address": "10jan2017wom1fttx5",
        "mobilePhone": "3556456745",
        "phone": null,
        "customerCategory": "VIP"
      },
      {
        "accountNumber": "0000160077",
        "accountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "accountType": "ACT25",
        "address": "10jan2017wom1fttx5",
        "mobilePhone": "3556456745",
        "phone": null,
        "customerCategory": "Default"
      },
      {
        "accountNumber": "0000160075",
        "accountStatus": "REGISTERED",
        "accountType": "ACT99",
        "address": "10jan2017wom1fttx5",
        "mobilePhone": "3556456745",
        "phone": null,
        "customerCategory": "Default"
      }
    ],
    "totalRecords": 14
  }
}
```

**fetchjson**

```
public class LoadJson {
    private Context mContext;
    private final String filename;

    public LoadJson(Context c, String filename) {
        mContext = c;
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open(filename);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

Comment: first check if the right list is passed to the adapter.Place a break point their and check the list you are receiving.If it is right then its a adapter issue

Comment: why you are calling the notifyDataSetChanged(), after you are setting the adapter? Try removing it.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() should be called when you have done any changes to the list and want that your listView should be reflected with that change.

Comment: @swetabhsuman - removed still same thing is going on

Comment: @ArpanSharma - Thanks for valuable comment..!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should Use `View holder pattern` edit your `getView` method and also add class `ViewHolder` to you adapter as follows:

```
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder mHolder;
            final Customer c = getItem(position);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_customer, null);
                mHolder = new ViewHolder();

                mHolder.tv_account_no = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_act_no);
                mHolder.tv_act_sts = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_act_sts);
                mHolder.tv_act_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_act_name);
                mHolder.tv_cust_cat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_cust_cat);

                convertView.setTag(mHolder);

            } else {
                mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            mHolder.tv_account_no.setText(c.getAccountNumber());
            mHolder.tv_act_sts.setText(c.getAccountStatus());
            mHolder.tv_act_name.setText(c.getAccountType());
            mHolder.tv_cust_cat.setText(c.getCustomerCategory());

            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            private TextView tv_account_no, tv_act_sts, tv_act_name, tv_cust_cat ;

        }
```

Edit: try to do that also

```
@Override
public Customer getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return customer.get(position);
}
```

Comment: @JigarMakwana have you checked the data list passed to adapter? is it correct?

Comment: @JigarMakwana please the edit in answer in `getView` and `getItem`

Comment: hello,I got the issue..I found that in fetchCustomers method i am getting only last values in all the arrayitems..So there must be error in iteration,can u help me for the same?

Comment: @JigarMakwana explain more, i don't understand you

Comment: @JigarMakwana your `fetchCustomers` method has no problems! BTW,  can you add code of `loadJSONFromAsset`

Comment: It is in "fetchjson" file

Comment: i don't see any thing wrong!, in your xml what are the width and hight of listview, please add it as well

Answer (score 0):

Set your adapter in your fetchCustomers() fuction

```
public class CustomerList extends Activity {
    ImageView ic_back;
    ListView lv_cust;
    LoadJson loadcustomers;
    String customers;
    ArrayList<Customer> customerList;
    CustomerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_list);
        lv_cust = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_customers);
        ic_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_back);
        loadcustomers = new LoadJson(CustomerList.this, "customers");
        customers = loadcustomers.loadJSONFromAsset();

        ic_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        //setting static data to list..
        fetchCustomers();

        //end


    }

    //void fill row data..
    void fetchCustomers() {
        customerList = new ArrayList<>();
        customerList.clear();
        try {
            JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(customers);
            JSONObject dataObj = mainObj.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray customerArray = dataObj.getJSONArray("result");

            for (int i = 0; i < customerArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = customerArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                customer.setAccountNumber(c.getString("accountNumber"));
                customer.setAccountStatus(c.getString("accountStatus"));
                customer.setAccountType(c.getString("accountType"));
                customer.setCustomerCategory(c.getString("customerCategory"));
                customerList.add(customer);
            }

adapter = new CustomerAdapter(CustomerList.this, customerList);
        lv_cust.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
        }
```

try this and this doesn't help. Please comment me will help you

Comment: @Jigar Makwana hope it helps you. I this doesn't help please reply me will give you better answer

Comment: you getting all values in your customerList before adapter set?

Comment: In your customerList after filling all data there is repeated values in this list? Or the above JSON is stored in customerList without repeat?

Comment: I know that. but debug your code and check In your customerList after filling all data there is repeated values in this list? Or the above JSON is stored in customerList without repeat? customerList having repeated value or not?

Comment: hello,I got the issue..I found that in fetchCustomers method i am getting only last values in all the arrayitems..So there must be error in iteration,can u help me for the same?

Comment: JSONArray customerArray = dataObj.getJSONArray("result"); what u get in customerArray? you getting correct JSON over here?

Comment: yes i am helping you bro. but you need to debug your code according to my suggestions

Comment: your code is correct according to this. From which URL you getting JSON? Can you share URL? So i will try myself

Comment: remone adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); from my above answer and try

Answer (score 0):

Finally...I found the solution to my problem that i have defined the string as "static" in my model classes,that is the main problem.I removed "static" and fixed the issue.

Got solution from below thread.

[Repeatable values in list in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506/why-does-my-arraylist-contain-n-copies-of-the-last-item-added-to-the-list)

Comment: Thanks btother for your time and support..(y) :)