# Arraylist keeps showing the last element n number of times

Tags: java, android

i have created an arraylist to store data which is fetched from an webservice.Data is fetched after every iteration but only the last element is displayed in arraylist.I tried various solutions but none of them seem helpful in my case

```
       public void onResponse(JSONObject paramAnonymousJSONObject)
      {
     JSONObject localJSONObject;
     int j;
     try
     {
       localJSONObject = paramAnonymousJSONObject.getJSONObject("status");
       j = localJSONObject.getInt("code");
       if (j == 200) {
         JSONArray carModelArray = paramAnonymousJSONObject.getJSONArray("carModels");
         for (int i = 0; i <= carModelArray.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject tariffResponse = null;
           JSONObject tariff = carModelArray.getJSONObject(i);
           try {
             carId = tariff.getString("id");
             segment = tariff.getString("segment");
             imageURL = tariff.getString("imageURL");
             tariffResponse = tariff.getJSONObject("tariffResponse");
             CarType = tariffResponse.getString("carModel");
             weekdayTariff = tariffResponse.getString("weekdayTariff");
             weekendTariff = tariffResponse.getString("weekendTariff");
             peakSeasonTariff = tariffResponse.getString("peakSeasonTariff");
             maintenanceCharge = tariffResponse.getString("maintainanceFee");
             securityDeposite = tariffResponse.getString("securityDeposite");
             ArrayList arrayList = TariffActivity.this.tariffModelsList;
             arrayList.add(new TariffModel(carId, CarType, imageURL, "\u20b9 " + weekdayTariff, "\u20b9 " + weekendTariff, "\u20b9 " + peakSeasonTariff, "\u20b9 " + securityDeposite, segment, "\u20b9 " + maintenanceCharge));
             TariffActivity.this.tariffAdapter = new TariffAdapter(TariffActivity.this.mContext,arrayList);
             TariffActivity.this.mRecyclerView.setAdapter(tariffAdapter);
           } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
           }

         }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: If you used Retrofit + Gson, you wouldn't need to manually parse your JSON

Comment: @shivadeep, TrafficAdapter is set at incorrect place, since it is inside the loop - value gets overridden and so the last value of the arraylist is set to it. 
So you have to assign the arraylist to the Traffic adapter after the loop ends, Please check my answer below

Comment: If I see this sort of problem my first question is: does `TariffModel` have only static fields? Because then no matter how many `TariffModel` objects you create all of them will have the same properties

Comment: no it doesn't contain

Comment: If none of the answers help I would still recommend that you add the definition of your `TariffModel` class (at least the field declarations and the constructor)

Answer (score 1):

Declare this outside the loop.

```
ArrayList arrayList = TariffActivity.this.tariffModelsList;
```

And these too outside the loop:

```
 TariffActivity.this.tariffAdapter = new TariffAdapter(TariffActivity.this.mContext,arrayList);
 TariffActivity.this.mRecyclerView.setAdapter(tariffAdapter);
```

And remove the above line from the loop. Because a New ArrayList is generating and new Adapter is being set for every iteration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @shivadeep Did you remove ArrayList arrayList = TariffActivity.this.tariffModelsList; this from inside the loop ?

Comment: @cricket_007 this is no  reassignment. I told him to declare only outside the loop not inside.

Comment: No, I mean `tariffModelsList.add()` should be able to be called directly. There is no need for the `arrayList` reference.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, surely he could. I've just followed the pattern of question maker. :p

Answer (score 1):

do something like below.

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject paramAnonymousJSONObject)
    {
        JSONObject localJSONObject;
        int j;
        try
        {
            localJSONObject = paramAnonymousJSONObject.getJSONObject("status");
            j = localJSONObject.getInt("code");
            if (j == 200) {
                JSONArray carModelArray = paramAnonymousJSONObject.getJSONArray("carModels");
                ArrayList arrayList = TariffActivity.this.tariffModelsList;
                for (int i = 0; i <= carModelArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject tariffResponse = null;
                    JSONObject tariff = carModelArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    try {
                        carId = tariff.getString("id");
                        segment = tariff.getString("segment");
                        imageURL = tariff.getString("imageURL");
                        tariffResponse = tariff.getJSONObject("tariffResponse");
                        CarType = tariffResponse.getString("carModel");
                        weekdayTariff = tariffResponse.getString("weekdayTariff");
                        weekendTariff = tariffResponse.getString("weekendTariff");
                        peakSeasonTariff = tariffResponse.getString("peakSeasonTariff");
                        maintenanceCharge = tariffResponse.getString("maintainanceFee");
                        securityDeposite = tariffResponse.getString("securityDeposite");

                        arrayList.add(new TariffModel(carId, CarType, imageURL, "\u20b9 " + weekdayTariff, "\u20b9 " + weekendTariff, "\u20b9 " + peakSeasonTariff, "\u20b9 " + securityDeposite, segment, "\u20b9 " + maintenanceCharge));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                TariffActivity.this.tariffAdapter = new TariffAdapter(TariffActivity.this.mContext,arrayList);
                TariffActivity.this.mRecyclerView.setAdapter(tariffAdapter);
```

You have to write `ArrayList` assignment outside of the `for loop` because if you write inside in loop then it reinitialization every time so element which you have to add is clear after reinitialization. That's why you have only last item in list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: @JoeC: I have added the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

move the `setAdapter()` out of the for loop and  define the `arrayList` variable outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `Adapter` in For Loop Also you are getting `List` each from your `Activity` while loop ruining :

Use Below Code :

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject paramAnonymousJSONObject) {
        JSONObject localJSONObject;
        int j;
        try {
            localJSONObject = paramAnonymousJSONObject.getJSONObject("status");
            j = localJSONObject.getInt("code");
            if (j == 200) {
                JSONArray carModelArray = paramAnonymousJSONObject.getJSONArray("carModels");
                ArrayList arrayList = TariffActivity.this.tariffModelsList;
                for (int i = 0; i <= carModelArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject tariffResponse = null;
                    JSONObject tariff = carModelArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    try {
                        carId = tariff.getString("id");
                        segment = tariff.getString("segment");
                        imageURL = tariff.getString("imageURL");
                        tariffResponse = tariff.getJSONObject("tariffResponse");
                        CarType = tariffResponse.getString("carModel");
                        weekdayTariff = tariffResponse.getString("weekdayTariff");
                        weekendTariff = tariffResponse.getString("weekendTariff");
                        peakSeasonTariff = tariffResponse.getString("peakSeasonTariff");
                        maintenanceCharge = tariffResponse.getString("maintainanceFee");
                        securityDeposite = tariffResponse.getString("securityDeposite");

                        arrayList.add(new TariffModel(carId, CarType, imageURL, "\u20b9 " + weekdayTariff, "\u20b9 " + weekendTariff, "\u20b9 " + peakSeasonTariff, "\u20b9 " + securityDeposite, segment, "\u20b9 " + maintenanceCharge));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                TariffActivity.this.tariffAdapter = new TariffAdapter(TariffActivity.this.mContext, arrayList);
                TariffActivity.this.mRecyclerView.setAdapter(tariffAdapter);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    public void onResponse(JSONObject paramAnonymousJSONObject)
          {
         JSONObject localJSONObject;
         int j;
           ArrayList arrayList = TariffActivity.this.tariffModelsList;

         try
         {
           localJSONObject = paramAnonymousJSONObject.getJSONObject("status");
           j = localJSONObject.getInt("code");
           if (j == 200) {
             JSONArray carModelArray = paramAnonymousJSONObject.getJSONArray("carModels");
             for (int i = 0; i <= carModelArray.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject tariffResponse = null;
               JSONObject tariff = carModelArray.getJSONObject(i);
               try {
                 carId = tariff.getString("id");
                 segment = tariff.getString("segment");
                 imageURL = tariff.getString("imageURL");
                 tariffResponse = tariff.getJSONObject("tariffResponse");
                 CarType = tariffResponse.getString("carModel");
                 weekdayTariff = tariffResponse.getString("weekdayTariff");
                 weekendTariff = tariffResponse.getString("weekendTariff");
                 peakSeasonTariff = tariffResponse.getString("peakSeasonTariff");
                 maintenanceCharge = tariffResponse.getString("maintainanceFee");
                 securityDeposite = tariffResponse.getString("securityDeposite");

                 arrayList.add(new TariffModel(carId, CarType, imageURL, "\u20b9 " + weekdayTariff, "\u20b9 " + weekendTariff, "\u20b9 " + peakSeasonTariff, "\u20b9 " + securityDeposite, segment, "\u20b9 " + maintenanceCharge));

               } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
             }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
               }    

               TariffActivity.this.tariffAdapter = new TariffAdapter(TariffActivity.this.mContext,arrayList);
              TariffActivity.this.mRecyclerView.setAdapter(tariffAdapter);
            }
```

Comment: @shivadeep set your adapter after for loop

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future. Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to `clear()` the arraylist before the loop, otherwise you get duplicate data from `onResponse` shown in the list.

Only extract JSON data and `add()` to the list inside the loop. If you still see copies of data, see [Why does my ArrayList contain N copies of the last item added to the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506/why-does-my-arraylist-contain-n-copies-of-the-last-item-added-to-the-list)

**Outside** the loop, you `setAdapter()` **OR**, you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` assuming you already have some `adapter`.

---

Also, `i <= carModelArray.length()` is going to throw an exception when using `getJSONObject(i)`.
Change to `i < carModelArray.length()`

Comment: Like I said, you need to clear before the loop. As the very first thing in `onResponse`. If you only see one item, then your JSON array could only have one item.

Comment: You mean `e.printStackTrace();`? Well, sure, you have an error. Please debug your app with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList arrayList = TariffActivity.this.tariffModelsList;

place this line before for loop

Comment: Place these two lines after for and try :              TariffActivity.this.tariffAdapter = new TariffAdapter(TariffActivity.this.mContext,arrayList);
TariffActivity.this.mRecyclerView.setAdapter(tariffAdapter);

Comment: i <= carModelArray.length() change this to i < carModelArray.length()