# ArrayList<int[]> displaying last array only

Tags: java, arraylist, combinations

I'm trying to write a "Mastermind" AI program and at the moment I'm trying to implement a naive AI which searches all possible 1296 combination of 4 pegs with 6 colours. 
I have written up the following `for` loop to print out all combinations:

```
int compguess[] = new int[4];
int a, b, c, d;
ArrayList<int[]> combination = new ArrayList<int[]>();
for (int z = 0; z < 6; z++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
                            a = z;
                            b = x;
                            c = i;
                            d = k;
                            compguess[0] = a;
                            compguess[1] = b;
                            compguess[2] = c;
                            compguess[3] = d;
                            combination.add(compguess);
```

When I run this code with `System.out.println("combination" + Arrays.toString(combination.get(k)));` at the end. This displays the combinations properly, however when I try to do the following:

```
 for(int i=0; i< height; i++){
                int[] temp = combination.get(i);
                for(int j = 0; j < 4 ; j++){
                    state[i][j] = temp[j];
                }
                guess.addActionListener(this);

        }
```

It only displays the last element (4,4,4,4) 40 times, instead I want it to be (0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,1), (0,0,0,2), (0,0,0,3), (0,0,0,4), (0,0,0,5), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,1,1), (0,0,1,2), (0,0,1,3) only 10 which is the size of the `height`

Comment: `combination.add(compguess);` doesn't copy `compguess`. You're putting the same array into the list over and over. Try `combination.add(new int[] { z, x, i, k});` instead.

Comment: it is working the way I want it too know. 

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my ArrayList contain N copies of the last item added to the list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506/why-does-my-arraylist-contain-n-copies-of-the-last-item-added-to-the-list)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using the same array every time, causing a change to one of them to change all, as they are, in fact, the same. Just reinitialize the array in the innermost `for` loop:

```
for (int z = 0; z < 6; z++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
                compguess = new int[4];
                // rest of your code
```