# Array elements are modified wrongly by call-by-reference

Tags: java

I want to add an array of integers to an `ArrayList`. The elements are filled with valid information under some conditions; otherwise the array is fill with -1.

```
    List<int []> starArray = new ArrayList<>();
    int [] star = {-1, -1, -1};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i < 5) {
            star[0] = i;
            star[1] = 2*i;
            star[2] = 3*i;
            starArray.add(star);
        } else {
            star[0] = star[1] = star[2] = -1;
            starArray.add(star);
        }
    }
```

Problem is that as soon as it goes to the `else` and set `star = 0`, all of the elements in `starArray` will set to -1. That means, after the loop, I get all -1 in the `starArray`. I want this result

```
0#0#0
1#2#3
2#4#6
...
-1#-1#-1
```

It seems that a reference is added to `starArray`. What I am trying to explain is that I want to create a temp array (star) with 3 elements. So star will take up 96 bytes. Then I move this 96 bytes to an ArrayList. Next I create another 3 element data in the same location of star and push another 96 bytes to ArrayList. So, by pushing two `star` to ArrayList, I will use

```
96 bytes => original star
96 bytes => first element of ArrayList
96 bytes => second element of ArrayList
```

So, how can I fix that?

Comment: By creating a copy of the array.

Comment: @chris: I don't want that! because starArray[0] is actually{0,0,0} and ...

Comment: @Kayaman: I wanted to create a single array and modify it multiple times. Otherwise, I have to create the array inside the loop and for large loops, it waste memory locations.

Comment: @Chris: same result.

Comment: You are in the "adding the same object" scenario of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843507/1361506)

Comment: You want to have a single array, yet you want it to have different values. That's not going to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding multiple references to the *same* array to the list, so changing one will inevitably change the others as well. You'll need to create a new array on each iteration:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int[] star = {-1, -1, -1};  // create a new array each iteration
...
```

---

In your current version, the picture looks like this:

```
star          [...]
             /  |  \
          +---+---+---+
starArray |   |   |   |
          +---+---+---+
```

Notice that all references actually point to a single array in memory. Now, we're doing this:

```
star   [...]  [...]  [...]
           \    |    /
          +---+---+---+
starArray |   |   |   |
          +---+---+---+
```

i.e. we're creating multiple physical arrays that can be modified independently. Sorry for the bad ASCII art.

---

If you're really concerned about memory usage, one approach you could try would be having a single array for the `{-1, -1, -1}`s, as long as you won't be mutating these arrays in the future:

```
int[] starNegOne = {-1, -1, -1};
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i < 5) {
        int[] star = {i, 2*i, 3*i};
        starArray.add(star);
    } else {
        starArray.add(starNegOne);
    }
}
```

This saves space whenever you're adding the `{-1, -1, -1}` arrays.

Comment: Please see my comment. Assume one array of 3 integers are created and then pushed to ArrayList. Will that store 6 locations in memory?

Comment: @mahmood "Locations in memory" isn't necessarily a meaningful metric, but in general each length-3 int array takes up some constant space (12 bytes + usual array/object overhead), so creating more arrays as we're doing here will naturally use more space.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are correct. Do not create array outside of for. Create inside and add it to list. Otherwise it keep modifies the same object multiple times and adds to the list multiple times and having the same values in the end.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  int [] star = {-1, -1, -1};
        if (i < 5) {
            star[0] = i;
            star[1] = 2*i;
            star[2] = 3*i;
        }
       starArray.add(star);
    }
```

And also remove the else completely as you are repeating the same code.

---

No, if you look your expected output

```
0#0#0
1#2#3
2#4#6
...
-1#-1#-1
```

All the arrays have distinct values and you still expecting one array should maintain this ? No IMHO.

Comment: Note that the assignment inside `else` is no longer necessary.

Comment: @shmosel The else part itself not needed. Just removed it.

Comment: Maybe for this snippet you are right. But the actual issue is not that. because I didn't wrote the original code. I tried to show a scenario to show the issue

Comment: @mahmood So if your example is not reflecting your original code, you asked a wrong question. Right ?

Answer (score 3):

insert a new anonymous array in every loop iteration

```
List<int[]> starArray = new ArrayList<>();
//int [] star = new int[];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i < 5) {
        //star[0] = i;
        //star[1] = 2*i;
        //star[2] = 3*i;
        starArray.add(new int[]{i, 2*i, 3*i});
    } else {
        //star[0] = star[1] = star[2] = -1;
        starArray.add(new int[]{-1, -1, -1});
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that create/new useless memory locations? I wanted to create a single array and modify it multiple times. Otherwise, I have to create the array inside the loop and for large loops, it waste memory locations.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to just split the loop into two, with `0 ..< 5` and `5 ..< 10`.

Comment: @mahmood In what way are they useless? They're storing your data.  If you only add one array, you will have only one array's worth of data.

Comment: every new is going to place those instance on the heap, but 10 objecst are not going to kill the performance of the jvm

Comment: You may be able to save memory by reusing the default (-1) array.

Comment: I supposed that adding to ArrayList will also create three memory locations. For 10 iterations, your code is fine. But for large iterations, e.g. 10,000,000,000 iterations, 10B arrays (each 3 int) are stored in memory. Then another ArrayList is stored in the memory also.