# Add values to Hashmap based on some criteria

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, hashmap

This below code checks id exist in ArrayList or not & then add it to map.

```
List<Map<Object, Object>> myListOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>>();
ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
al1.add("92");
al1.add("94");  
al1.add("91");  
al1.add("98");
Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();               
String id = "95,98,94";
for(int i=0;i<al1.size();i++)
{
    if(id.contains(al1.get(i)))
    {
        result.add("true");
        map.put("Access", true);                
    }            
    else 
    {
        result.add("false");
        map.put("Access", false);               
    }
    myListOfMaps.add(map);               

}
  for (int i = 0 ; i < myListOfMaps.size() ; i++) {
    Map<Object, Object> myMap = myListOfMaps.get(i);          
    for (Entry<Object, Object> entrySet : myMap.entrySet()) {                                
        System.out.println("Key = " + entrySet.getKey() + " , Value = " + entrySet.getValue());
    }
}          
System.out.println(result);
```

### output

```
Key = Access , Value = true
Key = Access , Value = true
Key = Access , Value = true
Key = Access , Value = true
[false, true, false, true]
```

arraylist result is fine but mapvalues returning true only.Please help me how to add k,v to map based on condition so that mapresult looks like this [{Access=false},{Access=true},{Access=false},{Access=true}].

Comment: See the second item on the top answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506

Comment: you are just putting one key and is overwriting the same key with different value. 98 is last one where you traverse and its in the list, hence you insert in map with key as "Access" and value as true and hence you get true everytime

Answer (score 1):

A hashmap is a key-value data structure. The way you store items is based on the **key**.

This being said, if you add a key `Access` to the map with the value `false` and print the map it will show : `Access: false`.

If you add again `Access` with the value `true` is not going to add a new key, is going to replace the previous value so it will print `Access: true`

So instead of adding the key `Access` to the map, add the id. `map.put(al1.get(i), true);`

Comment: While the explanation for the "why" is correct (though not complete; why is it printing the same `entrySet` 4 times?), the solution does not meet the output requirements of OP.

Answer (score 0):

You ahve to declare a new Map every time in your loop

```
//...
al1.add("98");
 //Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();               
String id = "95,98,94";
for(int i=0;i<al1.size();i++)
{
    Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
    if(id.contains(al1.get(i)))
    {
        result.add("true");
        map.put("Access", true);                
    }            
    else 
    {
        result.add("false");
        map.put("Access", false);               
    }
    myListOfMaps.add(map);               

}
//...
```

Comment: It will not solve the problem.. it will overwrite values everytime

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you:

```
List<Map<String, Boolean>> myListOfMaps = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> al1 = new ArrayList<>();
al1.add("92");
al1.add("94");
al1.add("91");
al1.add("98");

String id = "95,98,94";

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < al1.size(); i++) {
    Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    if (id.contains(al1.get(i))) {
        result.add("true");
        map.put("Access", true);
    } else {
        result.add("false");
        map.put("Access", false);
    }
    myListOfMaps.add(map);
}
myListOfMaps.forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: If you don't instantiate a new map each time, you'll use the same old reference, and the last value will be `true`, that's why you'll see true everywhere

Comment: do we really need to create a map on every iteration?

Comment: For this structure, where the OP needs a map (key-value pairs) with this for loop and this key and these values, I say yes. I would prefer another structure though, but I don't know what he/she needs.

Comment: Tamas Ambrus can u suggest me another structure