# Printing elements from a 2D ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create a phone book using a 2D ArrayList based on user input.  Here is my current code:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String> info = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();  
    ArrayList<String> entry = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("Enter first and last name: ");
    entry.add(addScan.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter Address: ");
    entry.add(addScan.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Add phone number: ");
    entry.add(addScan.nextLine());
    info.add(entry);
```

This is inside a do-while loop that exits when the user is done entering contacts.  I printed with System.out.println(info);
Here is the output when I printed:

```
    [[John Snow, 1234 King's Landing, 123-456-7890, Tyrion Lanister, 
    4567 Castle Black, 222-222-2222, Ned Stark, 999 Winterfell Lane, 
    777-777-7777], [John Snow, 1234 King's Landing, 123-456-7890, 
    Tyrion Lanister, 4567 Castle Black, 222-222-2222, Ned Stark, 999 
    Winterfell Lane, 777-777-7777], [John Snow, 1234 King's Landing, 
    123-456-7890, Tyrion Lanister, 4567 Castle Black, 222-222-2222, Ned 
    Stark, 999 Winterfell Lane, 777-777-7777]]
```

It correctly printed 3 elements but the elements it printed is the entire array instead of just the appropriate entry. Where am I going wrong?  I tried running a for loop and using info.get(i).get(0) + info.get(i).get(1) + info.get(i).get(2), but to no avail.  Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: post the code where you are printing the list.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't print anything from the list(s). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `ArrayList<ArrayList<String> info = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); ` 1. Here **>** is missing in `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>` and 2. `new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` could be written like `new ArrayList<>`, assuming you are using Java7 or higher.

Comment: Editted to add how I printed: System.out.println(info);

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does my ArrayList contain N copies of the last item added to the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506/why-does-my-arraylist-contain-n-copies-of-the-last-item-added-to-the-list)

Comment: Thank you @shmosel. That fixed it.  Sorry for not showing print statement. First time posting on stackoverflow.