# ArrayList of Objects not correctly referencing each object

Tags: java, object, arraylist

The solution was to remove static from my variables in the Account class.  The code now works as intended

I am trying to make a method that will check if a number is in an arraylist of objects

My initial thoughts were this but this is not working currently.  My main class is this withoutirrelevant code

```
private static ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
    //Creates the three default accounts
    Account ac1 = new Account("account1", 0001, 0);
    Account ac2 = new Account("account2", 0002, 0);
    Account ac3 = new Account("account3", 0003, 0);
    accounts.add(ac1);
    accounts.add(ac2);
    accounts.add(ac3);
}
public static void createAccount()
{
    Boolean doesContain = false;
    String logAccNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter your account Number");                 
    int tempAccNum = Integer.parseInt(logAccNum);
    doesContain = checkArray(tempAccNum);       
}
public static boolean checkArray(int checkNum)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <accounts.size(); i++)
    {
            if(accounts.get(i).getMyAccountNum() == checkNum)
            {
                return true;
            }   
    }
    return false;
}
```

My code in my Account class without irrelevant code is

```
private int myAccountNum;
private int myBalance;
private String myName;

public Account(String name, int accNum, int balance)
{
    this.myName = name;
    this.myAccountNum = accNum;
    this.myBalance = balance;       
}

public int getMyAccountNum()
{
    return myAccountNum;
}
```

The current issue with my code is that checkArray will only return true if the number entered in createAccount is the last default account created.  I believe that the myAccountNum variable in the Account class is staying the same after the last instance of it being constructed.

Lastly, I do not want to use iterators in the solution unless necessary, if you could use arrayList and for loops to create it that'd be greatly appreciated

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506 Also FYI, if you prefix your integer literals with `0`, that actually creates an octal literal.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0):

The attributes `myAccountNum`, `myBalance`, `myName` must be NON `static`, since these mean they exist independent of a class instance. When you instantiate new `Account`s, they'll all be referring to the same variables rather than possessing their own.

Your code say "share `myAccountNum`, `myBalance`, `myName`" between ALL the instances. It's not your intend.

Comment: That worked thank you so mucch

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the variable is static.https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-variable/ all static variables have the same value for all objects of that class