# implementing stack for ijvm instructions JAVA

Tags: java, stack, ijvm

I am implementing a simple ijvm using a stack in java, however, I encounter a very weird behavior and I have no idea why.
So for my stack class I have a constructor

```
  public Stack(int maxStacksize) {
    maxSize = maxStacksize;
    stack = new Word[maxSize];
    size = 0;
  }
```

(maxSize, stack and size declared are private variables of the class. and Word is my own class)
my push;

```
  public static void push(Word input) {
    stack[size] = input;
    size++;
  }
```

These seem fine to me, correct me if I'm wrong! So when the input is
BIPUSH 20
BIPUSH 40

I recognize the bipush instruction and push them on the stack per instruction, which works fine, I printed what I'm pushing and it first pushes 20 then 40. However after I push the 40, the 20 in the stack[0] turns into 40 for some reason? I printed the whole stack whenever I push something and so when pushing the 40, the stack turns into [40, 40] instead of [20, 40] and I have no idea why. I also print "size" every time and the size parameter seems correct whenever it's pushing. I know I don't have a check yet for if size is below 0, I'll add that later
Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that you push some `Word`, modify that same exact `Word` and push it again?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843507

Comment: Oh, yes I was just thinking about the statics. My Word class stored contents statically! I removed that and now it works. Thanks for the link, @JornVernee  =)

Comment: Ok great!, Then I'm closing this as a duplicate