# Hashmap shows same value for all keys

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a very simple code to populate hashmap with arrayList. Following is the code snippet

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String> > fieldValue = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();

tmp.add("f");
tmp.add("string");
tmp.add("false");
fieldValue.put("bas", tmp);

tmp.clear();
tmp.add("f");
tmp.add("string");
tmp.add("false");
fieldValue.put("usc", tmp);

tmp.clear();
tmp.add("f");
tmp.add("int");
tmp.add("false");
fieldValue.put("st", tmp);

for (Map.Entry r : fieldValue.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(r.getKey() + "\t" + r.getValue());
}
```

Following is the output when I execute it

```
st  [f, int, false]
usc [f, int, false]
bas [f, int, false]
```

Where is the problem? I was expecting there different values in hashmap value but they are all same. Am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is: you're putting the _same_ list `tmp` as the value for different keys and change the list before doing so. Instead of `tmp.clear();` do `tmp = new ArrayList<>();` and it should be fine. - Note that lists are _not_ immutable (if they were there would be no `clear()`).

Comment: how do I do this ? I expect value of tmp should be in hashmap before I clear it for next record

Comment: " I expect value of tmp should be in hashmap before I clear it for next record" - that's wrong thinking. What you put into the hashmap is a _reference_ to the list, not a copy. Hence calling `put()` 3 times with the same instance causes the same instance to be in the map 3 times - not 3 copies.

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does my ArrayList contain N copies of the last item added to the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19843506)

Comment: In contrast to other languages, Java does **not** copy your list when you pass it to a method. Java only passes the *reference* to the instance (this is called *pass-by-value*). The instance itself is still the same. So your variable `tmp` links to the same list that is saved inside the map.

Comment: You really want to read about pass by value vs pass by reference and such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
fieldValue.put(..., tmp);
```

does *not* clone the list `tmp`, it just puts into the map as a value the *reference* to the list.

So finally you have in the map the *last* content of the list.

You should *not* recycle the `tmp` variable, but you should always create a *new* independent list.

Answer (score 1):

`tmp.clear();` Just only removes data from the collection. But you still put the same object `tmp` for different keys. As it said above, you have to create a new collection `new ArrayList(tmp)`.