# print objects from HashSet collection

Tags: java, hash, collections, set

[image]I tried to print the objects from hashSet collection.  the console display only the last object(one object). when I used ArrayList with the same method, I'm able to print all the objects. i've used an iterator method in order to print the collection set, see the attached test.[image: Example of test result]

```
public Set<Coupon> getAllCoupouns() throws Exception {

    Coupon coupon = new Coupon();
    Set<Coupon> coupons = new HashSet<Coupon>();

    // Open a connection
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Utils.getDBUrl());
    // Define the Execute query
    java.sql.Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        // build The SQL query
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM COUPON";
        // Set the results from the database
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        // constructor the object, retrieve the attributes from the results
        while (resultSet.next()) {

            coupon.setId(resultSet.getLong(1));
            coupon.setTitle(resultSet.getString(2));
            coupon.setStartDate((Date) resultSet.getDate(3));
            coupon.setEndDate((Date) resultSet.getDate(4));
            coupon.setAmount(resultSet.getInt(5));
            CouponType type = CouponType.valueOf(resultSet.getString(6)); // Convert String to Enum
            coupon.setType(type);
            coupon.setMessage(resultSet.getString(7));
            coupon.setPrice(resultSet.getDouble(8));
            coupon.setImage(resultSet.getString(9));

            coupons.add(coupon);

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new Exception("Retriev all the coupons failed");
    } finally {
        // finally block used to close resources
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            // do nothing
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return coupons;
}
```

Comment: You're adding the same object to the `Set`. hence it only contains one object.

Comment: initialize the coupon Class inside the while loop.

Comment: Variant of [Why does my ArrayList contain N copies of the last item added to the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19843506/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

As you are initialising `Coupon` from outside the `while` loop, it keeps adding same object every time and hence, overwriting results in only last result being displayed.

What you need to do is to instantiate `Coupon` from within the `while` loop, e.g.:

```
public Set<Coupon> getAllCoupouns() throws Exception {
    Set<Coupon> coupons = new HashSet<Coupon>();

    // Open a connection
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Utils.getDBUrl());
    // Define the Execute query
    java.sql.Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        // build The SQL query
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM COUPON";
        // Set the results from the database
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        // constructor the object, retrieve the attributes from the results
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Coupon coupon = new Coupon();
            coupon.setId(resultSet.getLong(1));
            coupon.setTitle(resultSet.getString(2));
            coupon.setStartDate((Date) resultSet.getDate(3));
            coupon.setEndDate((Date) resultSet.getDate(4));
            coupon.setAmount(resultSet.getInt(5));
            CouponType type = CouponType.valueOf(resultSet.getString(6)); // Convert String to Enum
            coupon.setType(type);
            coupon.setMessage(resultSet.getString(7));
            coupon.setPrice(resultSet.getDouble(8));
            coupon.setImage(resultSet.getString(9));

            coupons.add(coupon);

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new Exception("Retriev all the coupons failed");
    } finally {
        // finally block used to close resources
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            // do nothing
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return coupons;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cupon` is always the same object. You make only one object of class `Cupon`, so the set contains only one object (you add always the same object). You must make a new object in each iteration in the `while` loop.