# All the nested dictionaries holds the same value?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build this datastructure with a nested dictionary:

```
["A",["A",123]],
["B",["B",123]],
["C",["C",123]],
```

And then loop over the data structure and print out the values.

The first problem is, that all the nested dictionaries are the same {"C",123}.
I think it's because it is the same object, but I don't know how to overcome that. Can I dynamically create new objects in the loop ?

The other problem i face is in the loop where I try to print out the Values.
The compiler says that it can't convert Dictionary to Dictionary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<string> liste = new() { "A", "B", "C" };
 
            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> DictOfDicts = new();
            Dictionary<string, int> DictOfData = new();

            foreach (string i in liste)
            {
                DictOfData.Clear();
                DictOfData.Add(i, 123);
                DictOfDicts.Add(i, DictOfData);
            }
            foreach (Dictionary<string, int> i in DictOfDicts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Some result");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Variable names should begin in lowercase, so they don't get confused with class names, which start in uppercase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my ArrayList contain N copies of the last item added to the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506/why-does-my-arraylist-contain-n-copies-of-the-last-item-added-to-the-list)

Comment: `foreach (Dictionary<string, int> i in DictOfDicts.Values)`

Comment: Just move your `Dictionary<string, int> DictOfData = new();` to inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I think this other question may solve the first part of the quesiton, but I'm skilled in java, so I'm not sure.

Comment: BTW, you just need this: `liste.ToDictionary(x => x, x => new[] { x, "123" })`

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues - No, the OP needs `liste.ToDictionary(x => x, x => new Dictionary<string, int>() { { x, 123 } })`.

Comment: @Kresten - You have 3 good answers and one bad one - and you've accepted the bad one. It does not solve your problem. It's effectively the same. Please reconsider your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var liste = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
var DictOfDicts = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();

foreach (var i in liste)
{
  // Create here a new DictOfData to add it to DicOfCicts.
  var DictOfData = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  DictOfData.Add(i, 123);
  DictOfDicts.Add(i, DictOfData);
}
```

The structure of `DicOfDicts` is,

```
["A",["A",123]],
["B",["B",123]],
["C",["C",123]],
```

Comment: Why do I need KeyValuePair in the foreach loop, when DictOfDicts already consists of KeyValuePairs? 
Why do I need to construct internalDict? Would my entry not already be a keyvalue pair?

Comment: I was just being explicit here. Even if you just have a `foreach (var item in DictOfDicts)` the item is also of type `KeyPair`. That's what dictionaries are made of, key-value pairs.

Comment: Seriously? You reuse the same instance of the dictionary and you selectively pick the one key to make the output match the OP's requirement. This is just smoke and mirrors.

Comment: If you write out the full content of the nested dictionary, with your code, you get this: `[A,[A,123],[B,123],[C,123]]
[B,[A,123],[B,123],[C,123]]
[C,[A,123],[B,123],[C,123]]`.

Comment: Can't blame someone when he's right @Enigmativity

Answer (score 2):

You declared `DictOfData` outside of the `foreach` loop. Then, all the operations inside the loop are done on the same object. So, you are clearing and filling the same dictionary object over and over again, on each loop iteration.

Just move you declaration of `DictOfData` to inside the loop, and you'll be good to go.

---

**Bonus**:

The whole operation you displayed in the questions can be done with just this:

```
liste.ToDictionary(x => x, x => new Dictionary<string, int>() { { x, 123 } })
```

Comment: Actually, you got that wrong. What the OP needs is `liste.ToDictionary(x => x, x => new Dictionary<string, int>() { { x, 123 } })`. Your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a slightly older C# language specification for the answer, and made the type declarations more clear for you to understand.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> parent = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();


foreach (string i in list)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> child = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    child.Add(i, 123);
    parent.Add(i, child);
}
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, int>> parentPair in parent)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> childDictionary = parentPair.Value;
    foreach (var childPair in childDictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(childPair.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation as to how you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very easy exercise to fix your code. Simply replace the `DictOfData.Clear();` with the declaration of `DictOfData` itself. In other words, move the line `Dictionary<string, int> DictOfData = new();` into the loop. That way you have a fresh instance of the nested dictionary rather than reusing the old one.

Try this code:

```
List<string> liste = new() { "A", "B", "C" };

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> DictOfDicts = new();

foreach (string i in liste)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> DictOfData = new();
    DictOfData.Add(i, 123);
    DictOfDicts.Add(i, DictOfData);
}
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, int>> i in DictOfDicts)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{i.Key},{String.Join(",", i.Value.Select(x => $"[{x.Key},{x.Value}]"))}]");
}
```