# "add()" function showing unusual behavior after clearing list and then adding again to the same list

Tags: java, list, debugging, arraylist

Given two 0-indexed integer arrays `nums1` and `nums2`, return a list answer of size 2 where:

- `answer[0]` is a list of all distinct integers in `nums1` which are not present in `nums2`.
- `answer[1]` is a list of all distinct integers in `nums2` which are not present in `nums1`.

*Note that the integers in the lists may be returned in any order.*

I have purposefully left print statement in there for debugging purpose.

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> findDifference(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
        Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>();
        List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i : nums2){
            set2.add(i);
        }
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i : nums1){
            set1.add(i);
            if(!set2.contains(i)) list.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        ans.add(list);
        System.out.println(ans);
        list.clear();
        System.out.println(list);
        for(int i : nums2){
            if(set1.add(i)) {
                list.add(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        ans.add(list);
        System.out.println(ans);

        return ans;
    }
}
```

input:

```
nums1 = [1,2,3]
nums2 = [2,4,6]
```

output:

```
[1, 3]
[[1, 3]]
[]
[4, 6]
[[4, 6], [4, 6]]
```

Final value of `ans` is supposed to be `[[1,3],[4,6]]` instead of `[[4, 6], [4, 6]]`.
Anyone one know why is it happening?

Comment: Yes - you've added `list` to `ans` twice. That's two references to the same object. Instead of `list.clear()` I suspect you want `list = new ArrayList<>();` so that you create a *new* list, instead of only clearing the existing one (which is still referenced in `ans`).

Comment: You add the same List twice to your `List<List<Integer>> ans` instead of adding 2 different List objects. Doing `and.add(list)` will **not** create a copy of `List<Integer> list`. So any modification you do on that list will be visible everywhere that List is referenced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my ArrayList contain N copies of the last item added to the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506/why-does-my-arraylist-contain-n-copies-of-the-last-item-added-to-the-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
ans.add(list);
```

Here you add reference to the object `list`, but it's a refference not a copy, so whatever you change in `list` it's also reflected in `ans`. If you add `System.out.println(ans)` after `System.out.println(list)`,

```java
ans.add(list);
System.out.println(ans);
list.clear();
System.out.println(list);
System.out.println(ans);
```

You'll see `[[]]`. So, content of the reference is empty. And then at the end of the script you simply add once more refence to `list`, so simply - whatever you have in `list`, you have twice in `ans`.
Solution for you is to add copy of the object instead of reference - use:

```java
ans.add(new ArrayList<>(list));
```

instead of:

```java
ans.add(list);
```

both times in your code

and if it's fine for you to use standard Java, you can simplify your code like:

```java
public List<List<Integer>> findDifference(Integer[] nums1, Integer[] nums2) {
    Set<Integer> set1 = Set.of(nums1);
    Set<Integer> set2 = Set.of(nums2);
    Set<Integer> set1_not2 = new HashSet<>(set1);
    set1_not2.removeAll(set2);

    Set<Integer> set2_not1 = new HashSet<>(set2);
    set2_not1.removeAll(set1);

    return List.of(new ArrayList<>(set1_not2), new ArrayList<>(set2_not1));
}
```